# how to auto-start/warm up .net core web app hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net core (3.1) web app which is hosted on IIS. I cannot figure out how to run a piece of code before the first request. I have done the following:

- set the 'start mode' of the app pool = "AlwaysRunning" and "Idle time-out" = 0
- set the 'preload enabled' = true on the web site

What i am missing is where/how i register the code/service that i would like to run before the first request comes in?

thanks in advance

Comment: any update? Does my reply answer your questions?

Answer (score 5):

> What i am missing is where/how i register the code/service that i would like to run before the first request comes in?

If you want to call one of your mvc or web api  after the application has start up completely to warm up your web application. You could try to use IHostApplicationLifetime's ApplicationStarted method.

This method will be called after the application started immediately.

You could inject IHostApplicationLifetime into Configure() method , then write the callback for ApplicationStarted that would be triggered when the application host has fully started.

More details, you could refer to below example:

Register httpclient service in Startup.cs  ConfigureServices method

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         
        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();


    }
```

Add   lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register callback in Configure method:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {               
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}");             

        });

        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IHttpClientFactory)) as IHttpClientFactory;

        lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(onApplicationStartedAsync(httpClientFactory).Wait);
    }

  

    private async Task<Action> onApplicationStartedAsync(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {

        var httpclient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        var httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:5000/api/values");

        var httpresponse = await httpclient.SendAsync(httpMessage);

        if (httpresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string res = await httpresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Result:

[image]