# How can I initialize a C# WEBAPI controller to preload data at startup?

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

I want to preload data for my WEBAPI application so that it does not take such a long time when the client calls-up.

I tried this through the below code example :

```
        public WordsController(IWordRepo repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _mapper = mapper;

        var wordItems = _repo.GetAllWords(); // I will add all these words in a singleton repository for any future lookups

    }
```

yet, the constructor is apparently called when the first client makes the request, which is already too late.

Please advise,
Geo

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62691135/7968203, if it helps you close your question and vote this answer up

Comment: If the data returned by GetAllWords() is the same for every user request then you can use some form of cache. Store the result of GetAllWords in cache at the first request (some time) then use it to fetch data from subsequent requests. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0